# Plotting dates and associated values from a dictionary with Matplotlib

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I have a dictionary containing instances of Python's `datetime.date` and associated numeric values (integers). Something like this but a lot larger of course:

```
{datetime.date(2016, 5, 31): 27, datetime.date(2016, 9, 1): 87}
```

I am trying to use Matplotlib in order to build a line graph that would display these numeric values (`y`) against these dates (`x`), in chronological order.

Something like this:

[image: [Example line graph][1] (I can't embed images.)]

I am new to Matplotlib and fairly new to Python as well. I tried a few solutions but they wouldn't add anything meaningful to the question.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using only `matplotlib`:

```
In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [2]: time_dict = {datetime.date(2016, 5, 31): 27, datetime.date(2016, 8, 1): 88, datetime.date(2016, 2, 5): 42,  datetime.date(2016, 9, 1): 87}

In [3]: x,y = zip(*sorted(time_dict.items()))

In [4]: plt.plot(x,y)
Out[4]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f460689ee48>]
```

This is the plot:

[image]

If you can use `pandas`, this task is also easy this way: relatively trivial:

```
In [6]: import pandas as pd

In [7]: df = pd.DataFrame.from_items([(k,[v]) for k,v in time_dict.items()], orient='index', columns=['values'])

In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
            values
2016-05-31      27
2016-09-01      87
2016-02-05      42
2016-08-01      88

In [9]: df.sort_index(inplace=True)

In [10]: df
Out[10]: 
            values
2016-02-05      42
2016-05-31      27
2016-08-01      88
2016-09-01      87

In [11]: df.plot()
Out[11]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x7f4611879160>
```

[image]

Comment: You could also use matplotlib's plot_date function: `plt.plot_date(x,y,'-')`. This helps with formatting the x axis.