# Cannot plot dates from pandas.core.frame.DataFrame; yields ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Im currently trying out jupyterlab (python 3) and I am running into problems plotting data from  a csv-file over time. I start my notebook with:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib as plt
import pandas as pd
```

I have a csv-file which looks like this:

```
Accessory: Eve Weather,
Room: outside,
Home: My Home,
Date,Temperature (Celsius)
2018-07-24T20:45:31,28.86
2018-07-24T20:35:31,29.06
2018-07-24T20:25:31,29.19
2018-07-24T20:15:32,29.31
2018-07-24T20:05:31,29.48
2018-07-24T19:55:31,29.58
2018-07-24T19:45:31,29.82
2018-07-24T19:35:32,30.32
2018-07-24T19:25:31,31.00
```

and I import it like this:

```
df=pd.read_csv("somefile.csv", sep=',' , header = 3, usecols=[0, 1], parse_dates=[0], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

now I would like to plot it. But how? I tried:

```
df.plot()
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520366/plotting-dates-and-associated-values-from-a-dictionary-with-matplotlib), but this throws the following error:

```
ValueError: view limit minimum -36812.62671585647 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units
```

*The error also occurs when using the jupyter notebook*. I am using Anaconda.

Comment: Can you also add the code that raised the error?

Comment: sure, sorry the formating was not so nice. I just used "pd.plot()"

Comment: Can you try `df.set_index('Date').plot()` instead? Looks like pandas is having trouble figuring out how to plot that when the datetime column is not the index.

Comment: `pd.plot` raises `AttributeError` here. Do you mean `df.plot()`?

Comment: right, @ImportanceOfBeingErnest  that was a typo.

Comment: THANKS @user2285236 now it's plotting!